# Orphan polygon not filling

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I'm trying to have an area of my PCB with the same geometry on the top and bottom copper layers, but I'm having trouble with the polygon on the top layer. I placed vias on the bottom contacts (which will be soldered to two-lead package), and set the 'orphans' setting on the top polygon that overlap the bottom contacts, but they don't fill when I ratsnest the PCB.

Is there any other setting I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: You could try to give the polygons a rank

Comment: @maikel Good shot, but I think he has a cutout polygon there. (Just out of curiosity, what kind of device is that?)

Comment: @Dzarda it's a photodiode with a rather unconventional package. The pad geometry is custom though, as I want to cool the device with a Peltier on the opposite side of the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I had the same issue once. I figured that the *polygon cutout* would destroy anything underneath it, regardless what *rank* it had.

---

There are basically two ways of solving it:

*1.* Create the outermost cutout so that it only affects the area you want. The cutout would then have a shape of an almost closed *letter C*.

*2.* Don't use a cutout at all. Just stack the inner polygons on top of the pour. Use *ranking(*)* in the combination with a different signal name to automatically create the isolation around those polygons.

Comment: _(*)_ Does anybody remember in what order those rank numbers have to be? I think the higher the rank of your polygon, the more "authority" it will have (to force lower ranking polygons out of the way)

Comment: This did the trick. Indeed the cutout area was the problem. With a higher rank on the center pads and a lower rank on the big ground plane, I got the desired layout.